# Mysterious characters at the end of E-Mail, received with socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, smtp

I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask, but I give it a try.

A device is sending an E-Mail to my code in which I am trying to receive the email via a socket in python, and to decode the E-Mail with  `Messsage.get_payload()` calls. However. I always have a `\n.\n` at the end of the message.

If the same device send the same message to a genuine email client (e.g. gmail), I get the correct original message without the `\n.\n`.

I would like to know what it is with this closing set of special characters in SMTP/E-Mail handling/sending, and how to encode it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you would have seen if you looked up the [SMTP protocol definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#page-33), a DATA section of a message transfer ends with `<CRLF>.<CRLF>`.

Comment: ah there is the definition. Thats exactly what I need. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

These are simply newline characters. In GMail they'll be processed and "displayed" so you don't see them. But they are still part of the email text message so it makes sense that `get_payload()` returns them.

Comment: But is there a python function to remove this to extract the original messsage from the payload?  Something `message.get_payload().get_real_payload()`...?