# Extracting email body in python

Tags: python, email, smtp

When an email is being sent to a computer, the DATA section of the message always ends with the character sequence `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` (see [RFC 2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#page-33) and a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108615/mysterious-characters-at-the-end-of-e-mail-received-with-socket-in-python)). When decoding an email message in python, there is a convenient function to get the payload of the message via `Message.get_payload()` (package `email`). But this 'payload' still contains the `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` sequence, which is suppressed when looking at emails with e.g. gmail.

My question: Is there a convenient function in python to get the REAL message, in which the additional characters are cut away? Or do I need to do some hack myself?

Comment: Let me quote from the answer of the post you've linked to in your message: "As you would have seen if you looked up the SMTP protocol definition, a DATA section of a message transfer ends with <CRLF>.<CRLF>."

Comment: @Joseph: I know this definition. But this was not my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing this (assuming it isn't a multipart message):

```
Message.get_payload().rsplit('\r\n', 2)[0]
```

In an example:

```
>>> s = 'Hi,\r\n\r\nThis is my email.\r\n.\r\n'
>>> print s.rsplit('\r\n', 2)[0]
Hi,

This is my email.
>>>
```

If it is only the `<CRLF>`'s you're worried about, then it doesn't get much cleaner than this. You might wrap it in a function to make it self-documenting, but to me this certainly beats including a custom library.

Comment: It makes me wonder why this is not included on the python library in the first place - in contradiction how things are normally done in python libs (clear, precise, useful and short). But the email package seem to be a bit awkward to me.

Comment: Well, the payload isn't necessarily plain text. For example, if `Message.get_content_type()` returns `'text/plain'`, then yes, you could just get the data. However, when it is a multipart message, it might be an attachment you are processing (say, a spreadsheet document). In that case, you need to decode that message part, and store the exact payload to disc. The `get_payload` function simply returns the data for a part of the message, in it's defined encoding. Your plain texts just have a `<CRLF>.</CRLF>` defined, as per the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` sequence at the end of the mail is an **artifact of the SMTP process** used to send the message. If you receive the message vai another method (POP, IMAP, reading a local mail box, etc), this sequence will not be present.

As this will only be present when your code is running as a SMTP server, the `email` package does not know how you got the message and treats the characters as part of the message, not as a message terminator.

Your SMTP server code should be stripping the last three characters (`.<CRLF>`) from the message before it passes it to the `email.Mesasage` class.

This would give SMTP server code something like this:

```
message = ""
while True:
    line = get_line()
    if line == ".\r\n":
        break
    message += line

email = Message.email(message)
```

This strips off the terminating characters, before converting the message to a `Message.email`.